# Angular ui-mask with Angular material date picker error

Tags: angular

I am using angular material date picker and I want to add slashes while typing date. I tried ui-mask with the mddatepicker available in angular material but it gives me error " cannot read toString of undefined" at value=value.toString() in mask.js.

But it works with the normal input element but not with the angular material date picker. Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try something in the code? if so update it to post

Comment: <md-datepicker type="text" class="custom-input" ng-model="datemask" ui-date-mask="99/99/9999"> </md-datepicker> I am trying to add ui-mask to the angular material date picker  it doesn't work. None of the ui-mask libraries seem to work with the date picker.